# benchmark test for browsers also depends on the number of extensions installed?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, benchmarking

I did a test in chrome and firefox, chrome with no extension, firefox with a dozen.
The test is form goolge (perhaps is optimized for chrome?), [here](http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/data/benchmarks/v5/run.html) and the result was:

> `Firefox: 118`
>
> `Chrome: 2479`

So I wonder: the benchmark is also influenced by the installed extensions or chrome is really so much higher than Firefox in performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes extensions affect performance... Especially in IE7/IE8.

As a general rule, use whatever extensions you want/need but consider that every one of them **may** affect your overall performance.

Some extensions however (e.g. Firebug) may slow down Firefox... but their assistance in developing web sites / applications far outweighs any performance hit.